# NullReferenceException on RouteTable.Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, nullreferenceexception, asp.net-routing

My ASP.NET MVC 3 web project was working fine, then I recompiled it and now I'm getting this error (some paths and namespaces changed to protect the innocent):

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 66:
>   RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute( Line 67:
>   "DefaultRoutes", // Route name Line
>   68:
>   "{module}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>   // URL with parameters
>
> Source File: ....\Global.asax.cs
>   Line: 66
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Project.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection
>   routes) in D:.....\Global.asax.cs:66 
>   Project.MvcApplication.Application_Start()
>   in D:.....\Global.asax.cs:139
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +4051717
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState
>   state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352 
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +407 
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +375
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +11642112
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +141
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4865877

I'm using IIS7.5 on Windows 7 x64, and the app pool is configured to run with .NET 4 and the 'Integrated' managed pipeline.

I've tried rebooting, and also cleaning out the bin and obj folders with no success.

Some extra information that turns out to be important - the line missing from the error page above:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultRoutes", // Route name
    "{module}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { module = _loadedModules.FirstOrDefault().Name, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: are you able to post your routes? it might help a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project dynamically loads modules and what wasn't clear from the original ASP.NET error page was that the NullReferenceException was being caused by the final line of the MapRoute() method call.

It turns out that _loadedModules was empty, so FirstOrDefault() was returning null - hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

In your global.asax.cs you can write like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(....);//you should use routes parameter rather than RouteTable.Routes   
}
```